# Strange symbols in password when installing Win7 => lost password

Tags: windows-7, mac, passwords, keyboard-layout, boot-camp

I think I'm victim of a rather curious mistake.

I installed Windows 7 through BootCamp, chose a password with some symbols (like #€<&, etc). What I didn't realize was that the keyboard layout at that time was probably different from what thought it was. So, now I don't actually know what my password is. I know what it should be, but not what I actually typed. The double entering of password obviously didn't help. To confuse it further, I have a Swedish keyboard.

I need to map what I thought I entered as password to what I actually entered. I've made the following table: (I think the drivers might play a part in this)

```
Installation    Mac Keyboard (Swedish)    US Layout      Win drivers
Current         Mac Keyboard (Swedish)    SWE Layout     Bootcamp drivers
```

I have tried to just change the layout to US when entering the password, but it did not help.

Any help greatly appreciated! I'd rather not reinstall Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google quicky leads to [this list of password recovery programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/passrecovery.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out! I might add that I have read access to the partition if that would help (I can still start the Mac in OS X).

Comment: Most -if not all- of these, are tools to boot your computer with. I honestly can´t tell whether they can handle the BootCamp installation or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't make the Mac boot into these.

Comment: Can you boot from the Win7 DVD ?

Comment: Yes, that works. I might have screwed up to make the USB bootable.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Win7. Apparently a `<` had become `§`.